# Read/Write remote text from Google Drive or similar from Android in c#

Tags: c#, android

So, the title may be misleading. I am building an android app that reads information from a text file, which is located on a cloud server (I would prefer to use either OneDrive, DropBox, or Google Drive [whichever is easiest]; others are fine). Periodically, the program will write information to the text file, still located on the cloud server. So, my question is twofold: Is it possible to read and write to a text file that is located on a cloud server? If so, how in the world would I complete this task? I have noticed the use of WebClient but I can't find a reasonable method or explanation on how this works. This program is coded in C#. This is what I have so far:

```
private string filename = "datafile.txt";
private List<Category> myList; //A list of an object that I developed ('Category')

//Allow the user interface to handle the error
public void readDatabase() {
   //Here is where the magic has to occur, in order to read the file
   ...
   //The usual reader that I use to read standard text files
   StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(filename);
   string line = "";
   while ((line = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
      //convertToCategory is my private method to convert the string to 
      myLine.Add(convertToCategory(line);
   fileReader.close();
}

public void writeDatabase() {
   //Here is where the magic has to occur, in order to write to the file
   ...
   //The usual writer that I use to write standard text files
   StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(filename);
   for (int i = 0; i < this.myList.Count; i++)
      //toString() is something was developed in my object called 'Category'
      fileWriter.WriteLine(fileWriter[i].toString());
   fileWriter.close();
}
```

I would love to use Google Drive as my cloud server, but I am open to other possibilities, if necessary. I just want an easy and efficient method to read/write to the text file.

Possible Implementations:
Have seen possible solutions, where the file is downloaded locally and then read like normal and then uploaded at time of closing. However, if I could get away with it, I don't want the text file to be downloaded.

I have, also, seen several places where a SQL database is used in this instance. But the unfortunate thing is that I don't have any knowledge in developing with SQL. So, using a SQL server would be ideal (because speed is very important for this application) but it will be difficult for me to understand how it works.

Comment: I think you skip using text file and write information to google sheets. You would have more flexibility. More info on library for c# https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet